# Is it a bad practice to return what was passed as an argument to a method in Java?

Tags: java

Is is a bad practice to make a method return what was passed to it as an argument after modifying this argument?

```
public int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] x) {

        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            x[i]=1;
        }
    return x;
}
```

As opposed to modifying and returning a copy of the argument.

```
public int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] x) {
        int[] y = x;

        for(int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
            y[i]=1;
        }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Only bad if it's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: You aren't doing anything, you're not making a copy.

Comment: It depends on what are you looking forward to happen with the parameter
You should take into account the type of parameter are you passing, for example if you pass an object and you change the reference or if it is a primitive variable

Answer (score 1):

If you are always returning the same array passed to the method, there's no need to return it. The method can simply have a `void` return type.

Take for example `ArrayList.toArray()` implementation :

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

It accepts an array as input and may return that same array instance (after modifying it), but in some cases it returns a different (new) array. That's the only reason for returning the array instead of having a `void` return type.

BTW, in your second code snippet you are returning the same array. `int[] y = x` does not create a copy. To create a copy use `int[] y = Arrays.copyOf(x,x.length);`. Whether or not creating a copy makes sense depends on the use case. If the purpose of the method is to modify the input array (as in `ArrayList.toArray()`), there's no point to make a copy of the input array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in returning the parameter, such method should not return anything. Instead, method should have `void` return type signature and a meaningful name like `applyLeftRotation`.

It's a bad practice when you modify the object you've passed as a parameter and then return it. Other developers will assume that you've returned a new object.

However, if you return a new object made from the one which was received as a parameter, it's a perfectly normal. These are so-called [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Also, something similar you can find in a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).